# Renaming a Column Name is SQL as for example [Incident#]

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to automate my workflow in SQL Server where I get an Excel file with a column name `[Incident#]`. I want to rename this column using a query and I can't seem to select this column by its name, here is my query:

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.testproc.[Incident#]', 'INCIDENT', 'COLUMN';
```

I will really appreciate if any of you could help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: sp_rename is used to rename an object (stored procedure, table, etc.) and not a column in a table or column reference. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Wil - Works fine for renaming columns...

Comment: Documented to rename columns: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

Comment: Not sure *how* you import this Excel file - have you looked at Integration Services (SSIS)? There, you could rename the column at import time, e.g. you could **map** the Excel column `[Incident#]` to be stored in a column called `Incident` (or better: `IncidentNo`) in SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

The square brackets need escaping

```
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.testproc.[[Incident#]]]', N'Incident', 'COLUMN'
```

Or use

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.testproc."[Incident#]"', N'Incident', 'COLUMN'
```